# Save entity with NULL value using CrudRepositoty in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra

Using Spring Boot, Cassandra, org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository for save entity.

I have next entity:

```
@Table("user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
...
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID> {}
```

Saving entity:

```
user.setName(null);
userRepository.save(user);
```

CrudRepository doesn't write attribute with NULL value to database because

```
if (value != null) {
                    log.debug(String.format("Adding insert.value [%s] - [%s]", prop.getColumnName().toCql(), value));
                    insert.value(prop.getColumnName().toCql(), value);
                }
```

in MappingCassandraConverter.java

Are There some way to save NULL value using CrudRepository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is fixed on June 28th. 
Have a look on the following url 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/72

> We now support the removal of columns for properties with null values
>   by allowing null values in Insert and Update statements written by
>   MappingCassandraConverter. Objects are stored with all persistent
>   properties. Insert and update perform no longer conditional inserting
>   of non-null values but take all values into account.

The current release is

```
<version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
```

however i think that this change is on

```
<version>1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

You can either wait for the next official release or you can go to this url
http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/#quick-start
and in the drop down menu next to the download select instead of 1.4.2 the 1.5.0 snapshot. If the system is in production I will advise you to wait for the next official release.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm using **<version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>**，but the problem still exists.
    if (value == null) {
     return;
    }

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
     log.debug("Adding insert.value [{}] - [{}]", property.getColumnName().toCql(), value);
    }

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **1.5.3.RELEASE**，but the problem still exists.

```
if (value == null) {
    return;
}

if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("Adding insert.value [{}] - [{}]", property.getColumnName().toCql(), value);
}
```